# html tag not create at the right place in the DOM

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create an accordian using `CSS`3 and `HTML5`, but I've faced a problem with the position of my HTML tag in the DOM

Here is my HTML (don't pay attention to PHP) :

```
<div id="listeChecklist" class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Check liste</div>
    <div class="panel-body">                
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th> 
                    <th>Heure</th>
                    <th>Machine</th>
                    <th>Référence produit</th> 
                    <th>Personne</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <section class="ac-container">
                    <?php
                    while($row = $requete->fetch()){ ?>
                        <div>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['heure']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['machine']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['ref']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['nom']." ".$row['prenom']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                </section>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in my `<table> <tbody>` I have a section that will be my container, and in the while loop (for every element I find in my database) I create a *div* which wrap the element that comes from the DB.

But when I open my page on the Internet I don't obtain the DOM that I want :

```
<div id="listeChecklist" class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <section class="ac-container"></section>
        <table class="table">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that the *section* is above the *table*.

Can I have some explanation about the mistake I've done ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `section` and `div` elements may not be direct children of `table`, `tbody`, `thead` or `tr` elements - they'd have to sit within a `th` or `td`; although I'd argue that this wouldn't be semantic. Your browser itself is realising that your HTML is incorrect, and is attempting to fix it by moving the `section` element completely out of your `table` altogether.

Furthermore, the `section` and `div` elements may not have `tr` children - they can, however, have child `table` elements.

I don't really know what you're trying to achieve here by wrapping things within the `section` or `div` element, but the `table` element is used to represent tabular data and nothing more.

#### Invalid HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <section>...</section>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Valid HTML

```
<section>
    <table>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: I have done this completely without thinking. I can use the `tbody` as my wrapper and my `div` tag can be replaced by using `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just "illegal" to have a `section` block element inside a `tbody`. Only `tr` are allowed as child elements of `tbody`. Your browser will try to clean your code and put the section outside the `table`